# HTML overwritten by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning!

I will start by saying i am fairly new to the world of Javascript and have some experience with HTML and CSS. In the code below i am simply testing out a form with a submit button. However i would like the information input to the form to then appear below the form when the user clicks the 'Sign Up' button.

I can place `document.write()` code where the `document.getElementById()` code is and it will write the results, however the form will disappear once the button is clicked.

I have looked at other questions however none seem to answer what i'm after as i'm not entirely sure what part i'm getting wrong.

If you could please explain the answer as simply as possible i would be grateful.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function click (){
            var add1 = document.getElementById("ad1").value;
            var add2 = document.getElementById("ad2").value;
            var add3 = document.getElementById("ad3").value;
            var postc = document.getElementById("pcode").value;
            var tel = document.getElementById("tno").value;
            var order = document.getElementById("ot").value;
            var deliv = document.getElementById("dt").value;
            var amount = document.getElementById("money").value;
            var email1 = document.getElementById("email").value;

            document.getElementById("addr1").innerHTML = add1;
            document.getElementById("addr2").innerHTML = add2;
            document.getElementById("addr3").innerHTML = add3;
            document.getElementById("pc").innerHTML = postc;
            document.getElementById("telephone").innerHTML = tel;
            document.getElementById("ordertype").innerHTML = order;
            document.getElementById("deliverytype").innerHTML = deliv;
            document.getElementById("currencyamount").innerHTML = amount;
            document.getElementById("emailer").innerHTML = email1;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Address 1</td><td><input type="text" name="addressaddress" id="ad1"     placeholder="House Number"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address 2</td><td><input type="text" name="ad2" id="ad2"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address 3</td><td><input type="text" name="ad3" id="ad3"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Postcode</td><td><input type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Telephone</td><td><input type="text" name="tno" id="tno"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Order Type</td><td><input type="text" name="ot" id="ot"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Delivery Type</td><td><input type="text" name="dt" id="dt"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>How much do you want to spend?</td><td><input type="text" name="money" id="money"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="mybtn" onClick="Click();"></input>  </td></tr>     
    </table>
</form>

<p id="addr1"></p>
<p id="addr2"></p>
<p id="addr3"></p>
<p id="pc"></p>
<p id="telephone"></p>
<p id="ordertype"></p>
<p id="deliverytype"></p>
<p id="currencyamount"></p>
<p id="emailer"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks guys! :)

PS. i realise my naming conventions aren't the clearest!

Comment: `document.write` called after the initial parsing of the document __replaces__ the whole document – that is (/should be) common knowledge. Use other techniques to “write” content into a document dynamically, f.e. `innerHTML` or dynamic element creation.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, taking the 'document.write' advice into account, my code above does not use this, however the innerHTML still does not appear when the form is submitted, is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first reaction is the unhelpful one - "why on Earth would you do that?" - please make sure you aren't creating some bizarro UI that's user-hostile. It's often a good idea to have non-JavaScript fallbacks too, because non-JS browsers really do exist, both for security and footprint reasons.

OK, so that aside... `:-)`

As others have pointed out in the time I've taken to write this, you're calling function `Click` from the submit button's `onClick` attribute but you're declaring a function `click`, which is a different name (lower case 'c'). However, change it all to `click` (lower case) and it'll fail - in the context of script execution in either the button's `onclick` or form's `onsubmit` environments, there's already a native function called `click` defined and that'll run instead. Your own script won't.

This arises from age, essentially. The older the functionality you try to use in browsers and JavaScript, the more mucky and less consistent it tends to be as we're heading back to the so-called "DOM 0" undocumented days of Netscape fighting Microsoft with unstandardised bodges added in left and right and centre. Although you acknowledge that your naming conventions aren't the best, I suggest you make them better - use longer and more descriptive names to avoid accidental collision with things built into the browser and *definitely* avoid really generic things like `click` to preserve your sanity.

I know it's tempting to hack up examples and throw things together quickly but that can lead to confusion, especially the way you have similarly named input and display elements, plus the ambiguous / generic script names. You need to get things clear in your own head:

- Which elements are which, easily identified wherever their names appear
- What exactly a function does ('click' what, exactly? 'form_submit_click_handler' maybe?)
- Determine the *standards mandated* order of event execution; click handler first, form submission first, undefined?
- Make sure you've read about what the return values of these functions should be - they *are* significant and important, and inconsistent too (see above) - much care is required

Often it's better to use longer form versions of this stuff, with higher level but better defined interfaces, even if it means more typing - don't be lazy! `:-)` - e.g. attach all your JavaScript event listeners in an `onload` style handler with `<element>.addEventListener` rather than hacking though DOM 0 cruft like `onclick`.

In style terms, your HTML is pretty rotten to be honest - apart from the missing closure of the `body` and `html` tags, you're not giving the required attributes to `script` and using a table for the layout of the form is pretty outdated. Using `<label>` for the "Address 1" text and so-on, followed by the `<input>` tags would be better, with CSS providing width cues to get the alignment you want. Personally I do myself often fall back to basic tables because CSS can be such a pig for some basic things that tables make easy, but in this case it would seem easy enough to use CSS and clean up the markup considerably. That'll help with screen readers, maintenance and probably improve rendering on small screen devices.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for taking the time! Fortunately i've not been let loose with any web forms so far and this is just me practising! I'm teaching myself Javascript so this was my first attempt at a form, the form validation function i have written works fine, which is denoted by the "onsubmit = "validateForm()"" found in the <form> tag. And i fully admit my own laziness is responsible for the naming. As a caveat, i have replaced the 'click' name as you suggested, and the address appears for a second and disappears, any idea's on how to make it stay? Also any resources on good HTML etiquette?

Comment: The HTML 'etiquette' stuff is really the HTML standard, which mandates various things. Getting to know the W3C site is a good start. For HTML validation, see:

  http://validator.w3.org/

(Formatting is not retained in comments, annoyingly) - or use a browser with an extension or built-in "validate" option.

Comment: Your form submits to nowhere (there's no URI in the <form>) tag, so that means it just submits back to the same page. So what's happening is that your JS code runs, the form then is submitted and the browser is thus reloading the same page. That's why the content vanishes.

Again, as above, see documentation on return values for your event handlers to work out how to prevent submission of the form in JavaScript, should that be your aim. The W3C specifications are one route to find out about this; see also Google and e.g.:

  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/dom0.html

Comment: Finally, if you're serious about learning JS properly - rather than by sort of hacking from examples on the Web, many of which really won't be the greatest resources to learn from, given the lack of ordering, structure and variable age of articles/blogs/etc. - you could do worse than invest in this:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do

...which is by many considered to be the "standard text" for learning all about the language.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Click();`, but you defined `click()`. JavaScript is *case sensitive*.

Also, `<input />` is a standalone tag, not a closing tag. There's no `</input>` necessary (in fact, it's invalid).

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" id="mybtn" onClick="click();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var add1 = document.getElementById("ad1").value;
            var add2 = document.getElementById("ad2").value;
            var add3 = document.getElementById("ad3").value;
            var postc = document.getElementById("pcode").value;
            var tel = document.getElementById("tno").value;
            var order = document.getElementById("ot").value;
            var deliv = document.getElementById("dt").value;
            var amount = document.getElementById("money").value;
            var email1 = document.getElementById("email").value;

            document.getElementById("addr1").innerHTML = add1;
            document.getElementById("addr2").innerHTML = add2;
            document.getElementById("addr3").innerHTML = add3;
            document.getElementById("pc").innerHTML = postc;
            document.getElementById("telephone").innerHTML = tel;
            document.getElementById("ordertype").innerHTML = order;
            document.getElementById("deliverytype").innerHTML = deliv;
            document.getElementById("currencyamount").innerHTML = amount;
            document.getElementById("emailer").innerHTML = email1;

            //document.myForm.submit();
            /*
            this will submit the form and will refresh the page so the content will disappear
            */


            return false;
            /*
            due to this content will be displayed and form will not be submitted until be uncomment the above form submission
            */
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Address 1</td><td><input type="text" name="addressaddress" id="ad1"     placeholder="House Number" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address 2</td><td><input type="text" name="ad2" id="ad2" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address 3</td><td><input type="text" name="ad3" id="ad3" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Postcode</td><td><input type="text" name="pcode" id="pcode" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Telephone</td><td><input type="text" name="tno" id="tno" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Order Type</td><td><input type="text" name="ot" id="ot" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Delivery Type</td><td><input type="text" name="dt" id="dt" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>How much do you want to spend?</td><td><input type="text" name="money" id="money" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />  </td></tr>     
    </table>
</form>

<p id="addr1"></p>
<p id="addr2"></p>
<p id="addr3"></p>
<p id="pc"></p>
<p id="telephone"></p>
<p id="ordertype"></p>
<p id="deliverytype"></p>
<p id="currencyamount"></p>
<p id="emailer"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not a fan - yes, you've made *something* work, but it isn't clear what that something is and you've ended up with function "validateForm" very badly named. It doesn't validate. "displayFormContents" maybe. This stuff is important, since it's how the confusion evident in the question arose in the first place.

Comment: First let me know what exactly you want. Do you want the code to validate the form? I am not getting why you want to display the values below the form.

Comment: Hi Kundam, i have left off the validateForm() code as it works so far. If you are interested i will paste at [link](http://pastebin.com/yZ3gvB8d), please check it out!